# 301 redirect DNS issues

Tags: linux, redirect, networking, nginx, dns

I think I screwed up something in my DNS configuration and now its bugging me for hours. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I own a domain lets call it **abc.com**

Before all the issues happened DNS was configured in the following way at my registrar:

```
abc.com         'A' record  Points to a wordpress server
www.abc.com     'A' record  Points to a wordpress server
app.abc.com     'A' record points to amazon server.
```

We had a requirement where I had to achieve the following:

```
abc.com         point to amazon server. //not the wordpress but amazon.
www.abc.com     point to a wordpress server
app.abc.com     point to amazon server.
*.abc.com       point to amazon server
```

What I did to achieve this I believe is causing me all the issues.  I went ahead and modified the DNS records in the following order

```
abc.com         'A' record points to amazon server. //earlier pointed to wordpress
www.abc.com     'A' record points to a amazon server 
app.abc.com     'A' record points to amazon server.
```

I changed my nginx configuration in 
such a way that

**http://*.abc.com would always redirect to https://abc.com and I made the redirect permanent**

```
server{
    listen                80; # default;
    server_name           abc.com *.abc.com;

    location / {
            include proxy_params;

            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect    off;
            proxy_headers_hash_max_size 8192;
            proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 256;
            return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```

---

After a while I realized I made a mistake as I wanted the www.abc.com to point to wordpres. So I went ahead and modified the DNS records again.

```
abc.com         'A' record points to amazon server. 
www.abc.com     'A' record points to a wordpress //earlier pointed to amazon/nginx
app.abc.com     'A' record points to amazon server.
```

And whatever I do, the change to www.abc.com isn't reflected on the web. It just redirects to the amazon server. I tried it using different machines, installed browsers afresh still no luck.

I tried **pinging** abc.com and www.abc.com and they do point to amazon and wordpress (as configured in DNS), I even tried checking DNS propagation at whatsmydns.com and it shows the IPs based on my DNS conf. But I don't understand why they don't work in the browser.

I tried checking the redirect flow of the site at  http://redirectcheck.com/index.php and it still shows 301 permanent redirect despite me going ahead and modifying the DNS records.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This quesiton is more appropriate for http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

You've made what's called a "DNS propagation" - which can take up to 24 hours to take effect - [Domain Names - How long do DNS changes take?](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/domain-names/dns-nameserver-changes/domain-names-dns-changes)

If 24 hours have passed, try [Clearing the DNS Cache on Computers and Web Browsers](https://support.opendns.com/entries/26336865-Clearing-the-DNS-Cache-on-Computers-and-Web-Browsers)

Comment: Yonatan - I'm afraid thats not correct. I already mentioned in my question that DNS propagated and I could verify it using whatsmydns.net and ping